# Do TFS 2010 builds have file path limitations?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

We recently started getting the following error message in TFS 2010 automatedd builds:

> C:\Builds\1\MyProject\MyProject Release\Sources\MyProject\MainLineMyProject.SharePoint.EnterpriseUI.SiteDefinition\Features\MasterPagesMyProject\MasterPagesMyProject.feature: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Initially I thought this is due to Sharepoint, but some further research points me in the TFS direction. Any way other than truncating the path around this problem?

Comment: What part of that message is ambiguous? The path is too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a TFS limitation inherited from Windows.

See here for possible workaround:

http://geekswithblogs.net/MikeParks/archive/2009/06/20/team-build-260-character-path-limit-workaround.aspx

Comment: "Inherited from Windows"? You're running on Windows. No tool will be able magically to avoid the limitations of Windows.

Comment: Actually, it's more of a .NET Framework limitation. Although I'm sure that if you created a file with a path longer than 260 characters, there are a lot of applications that couldn't handle it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders there are work-around for everything. I think you should take a look at Peter's [LongPath](https://github.com/peteraritchie/LongPath) library. I do agree that this is a limitation on Windows API itself, and even changing that is possible. By why would they take a risk of overhauling their stable codebase. maybe we can expect a change with the Windows 9, but so far it is a [limitation](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2156195-fix-260-character-file-name-length-limitation)

Comment: The limitation is not strictly speaking of Windows as Win32 supports long file paths if you alter your calls to the API. It is unfortunate that .NET doesn't use the Win32 API to make use of long paths correctly.